# Not able to set condition in *ngIf angular2 directiive

Tags: angular

I have put a check in my html on the length of a property

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="!products.length">
   <div class="col-12">No Records Found</div>
</div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="products.length">
    <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th>category</th>
                <th>price</th>
                <th>quantity</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am fetching the data from a service. Here is my component

```
export class ManageComponent implements OnInit {
    products: any[];

    constructor(private sharedservice: SharedService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData() {
        this.sharedservice.getData()
            .subscribe(
                products => {
                    console.log('p: ', products);
                    this.products = products
                }
            )
    }
}
```

So when there is no data present in the db it simply returns empty array.

But angular2 is showing error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

any idea on this ??

Answer (score 3):

`products` is not defined by the time it is assigned from your async operation(`sharedservice.getData()`). What you can do is to rewrite your ngIfs. So they will check if `product` is defined in the first place.

Example:

```
*ngIf="products && products.length"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use safety operator as well :

```
   <div class="row" *ngIf="products?.length">
```

Comment: yes, I have used this. What is the meaning of this safety operator ?

Answer (score 2):

Need to declare products as array type;

like this -

products: any[] = [];